# Triple integrals over half a sphere

Tags: definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the following integral:

$\int\int\int y·dxdydz $

Over the following domain:

> D= {(x,y,z)| $x^2+y^2+z^2\le R^2, y\ge 0$}

So according to the following coordinate system:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/3D_Spherical.svg/558px-3D_Spherical.svg.png

Where y= $rsin(\theta)sin(\phi)$.

According to the above graph both $\theta$ and $\phi$ should be between 0 and $\pi$.

So the integral I end up with is:

$\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{R} r^3sin^2(\theta)cos(\phi) drd\theta\ d\phi   $

But this integral clearly equals zero as $\int_0^{\pi}cos(\phi)d\phi$=0.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where'd the $\sin\phi$ go?  $y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ but there's no $\sin\phi$ in the integrand after the coordinate change.

Comment: Integrand should be $r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cdot r^2\sin(\theta)$. Integrate this and you get $$\frac{R^4\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: I feel stupid now! Thank you :(

Answer (score 0):

Your $\sin\phi$ became a $\cos\phi$ after the coordinate change.  Fix that and you should get
$$ \int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^R r^3 \sin^2\theta\sin\phi \, dr \, d\theta \, d\phi = \frac\pi4R^4 $$

Also, just FYI, for triple integrals you can use `\iiint` and for sines and cosines you can use `\sin` and `\cos`.  `\iiint` produces $\iiint$, which looks cleaner than $\int\int\int$